# How can I make only a part of this page scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have a specific layout which I've recreated with vanilla here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.external-flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.external-title {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.internal-flex {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.internal-title {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.table {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.divider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.dynamic-content {
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="external-flex">
    <div class="external-title">
      EXTERNAL TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="internal-flex">
      <div class="internal-title">
        INTERNAL TITLE
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="table">
          TABLE
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="dynamic-content">
          <div class="item">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
          <div class="item">6</div>
          <div class="item">7</div>
          <div class="item">8</div>
          <div class="item">9</div>
          <div class="item">10</div>
          <div class="item">11</div>
          <div class="item">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

The `main` has height of `100dvh` and the goal is to have the blue container (the one with the cards) to scroll.

Instead, the entire page scrolls. Try as I might I could not get it to not scroll. I know scrolling internal divs requires having a strict size but I did check thrice and everything ends up having a height, either via percentage or via flex, so at this point, I am at SO's mercy.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS little bit say:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.external-flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.external-title {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.internal-flex {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 12px;
}

.internal-title {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.table {
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.divider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.dynamic-content {
  height: 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
  /* You may add somethinglike this */
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="external-flex">
    <div class="external-title">
      EXTERNAL TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="internal-flex">
      <div class="internal-title">
        INTERNAL TITLE
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="table">
          TABLE
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="dynamic-content">
          <div class="item">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
          <div class="item">6</div>
          <div class="item">7</div>
          <div class="item">8</div>
          <div class="item">9</div>
          <div class="item">10</div>
          <div class="item">11</div>
          <div class="item">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```